# Combining CSV files into Dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I am trying to add data from several files in a folder to a data frame. Each .csv file has varying lengths but has the same number of columns. I am trying to add all of them to one data frame with ignoring the index so that the new data frame is just vertically combined. For some reason every time I try to concatenate the data I am left with ~ 363 columns when there should only be 9. Each csv file has the same number of columns so I am confused.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd 
import glob 

cwd = os.getcwd()
folder = cwd +'\\downloads\\prepared_csv_files\\prepared_csv_files\\' 
all_files = glob.glob(folder + "/*.csv") 
    
li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I have also tried

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(li, columns = ['tool','pressure'])
# and I name all columns not doing it now
```

Answer (score 0):

here final is the name of the final dataset.

I am assuming tool and pressure are the columns name in your all .csv files

```
final = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['tool','pressure'])
    for filename in all_files:
          df = pd.read_csv(filename)
          df = pd.DataFrame(df)
          final = pd.concat([final,df],ignore_index= True,join="inner")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I used this and it worked for my original problem, however now it will only show the values of the last file and not even the full values of the file.  The df should have around 26k values and it only has 95. The last csv read in has 394 alone.

Comment: @Tyler2P okay, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: @code_killa  Column name in each csv file is 'tool','pressure'  right?
Also my code is reading each .csv file and concatenating them in the final variable.